# Confirmation on probability identity

Tags: probability

I need a confirmation regarding a probability formula:

$ P(A\cup B)=P(A\cap B)+P({ A }^{ c }\cap B)+P(A\cap { B }^{ c }) $

I am asked if this identity is true.

For me, it is true.
Can you please confirm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "For me, it is true." Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Draw a Venn diagram of the sets $A$ and $B$. Color the three sets $A \cap B$, $A^C \cap B$ and $A \cap B^C$. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Note that (letting S= sample Space)
$$(A\cap B)\cup(A^{C}\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{c})=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^{C})\cup (A^{C}\cap B)=(A\cup(B\cap B^{c}))\cup(A^{C}\cap B)=(A\cup\emptyset)\cup(A^{c}\cap B)=A\cup(A^{c}\cap B)=(A\cup A^{c})\cap (A\cup B)=S\cap(A\cup B)=A\cup B$$

and that

(1) $(A\cap B)\cap(A^{c}\cap B)=A\cap A^{c}\cap B\cap B=\emptyset\cap B=\emptyset$

(2) $(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap B^{c})=A\cap A\cap B\cap B^{c}=A\cap \emptyset=\emptyset$

(3) $(A^{c}\cap B)\cap(A\cap B^{c})=A^{c}\cap A\cap B\cap B^{c}=\emptyset\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$

Thus $(A\cap B), (A\cap B^{c}), (A^{c}\cap B)$ are all pairwise disjoint and their union is $A\cup B$. So just use fact probability of a union of pairwise disjoint events is just sum of those events

Answer (score -1):

[sorry, didn't see the other answer, which says the same as mine]

if you have the decomposition of $A \cup B$ into three disjoint sets, then the result follows from the additivity of the probability measure. so can you prove that:
$$
A \cup B = A \cap B + A \cap B^c + A^c \cap B
$$
where the $+$ means disjoint union?

Comment: Yes we get disjoint sets that cover the whole area. So the formula is OK. that was my thought, but I wanted an external confirmation. I had a doubt.